# Make UIBarButtonItem appear disabled?

Tags: ios, uibarbuttonitem

I know about `self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.enabled = NO`, but how do I make a `UIBarButtonItem` *appear* disabled but actually detect when the user taps it? I want to do this in case I want to alert the user what is incomplete.

Answer (score 1):

The way i'd do it is not disable it, but when its 'disabled' set another bar button item there with a disabled looking background and no alternate image for the tap event. Then when it is tapped, show an alert view to tell them that it isn't available:

```
- (void)init
{
    [self setDisabledBarButtonItem:[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWith...];
    [disabledBarButtonItem addTarget:......];
    [self setEnabledBarButtonItem:[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWith...];
    [enabledBarButtonItem addTarget......];

}

- (void)timeToDisableBarButtonItem:(id)sender
{
    [self.navigationitem setRightBarButtonItem:disabledBarButtonItem animated:NO];
}

- (void)timeToEnableBarButtonitem:(id)sender
 {
    [self.navigationitem setRightBarButtonItem:enabledBarButtonItem animated:NO];
}
```

Good UX practises state however that you shouldn't need to tell your user that it is disabled, they should be able to tell without an alert. Easier said than done of course :)

Would love to see a cleaner solution than this, but its the only way I think your going to get it to work.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thanks, Aron. I might just follow good UX practices for now and make obvious what's incomplete. :)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, except I was trying to make a disabled button look enabled.  I found a much nicer solution that is available in iOS 5.0 - you can use `setTitleTextAttributes:forState` to control the appearance of your enabled (or in my case, disabled) state, as well as many other states.

API reference:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIBarItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIBarItem/setTitleTextAttributes:forState:

In most cases you won't want to do this.  However, in my case it proved necessary.  I have a toolbar button that is a document title, and pressing it while in edit mode allows brings up a UITextField to edit the title, but in run mode the title should not be editable while still looking like a title, rather than a disabled button.  By changing the text color to match my enabled state, I achieved the look and behavior I wanted without having to swap the button or the action out (and consequently have to synchronize my title text across three places instead of two).